# How to join one HABTM model by values of another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have three models:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :models
  has_and_belongs_to_many :makes

class Make < AR::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :campaigns
  has_many :models

class Model
  has_and_belongs_to_many :campaigns
  belongs_to :make
```

I have a `@campaign` variable and a special `@campaign.models` value.

How can I find all `make`s that are related to `@campaign.models`?

The simplest solution is `Make.where(id: @campaign.models.pluck(:make_id)`, but it's not efficient.

Comment: Why won't that be efficient?

Comment: Makes.where(:id => @campaign.models.pluck(:make_id) ) or you can use join query.

Comment: try add `has_many :models_makes, through: :models, class_name: Make`